# Remove payment method

Tags: magento2, admin, payment-methods, configuration

i'm magento 2 newbie, i want to remove some payment method from the admin Store -> Configuration screen
[image]

is there anyway to do it?
many thanks.

Comment: which payment method you want to remove? And actual why you need to remove?

Comment: i want to remove PayPal and Braintree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by disabled the extension.

Please go to the `app/etc/config.php` and checked which one you want to disable.

Right now for example you want to disabled `PayPal_Braintree` then find it from this file.

From `'PayPal_Braintree' => 1,`

to `'PayPal_Braintree' => 0,`

Replace 1 with 0 and it will be disabled.

Please flush the cache via this command.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Happy Coding @namikaze